# How I get Cinnamon sound applet source code

Tags: cinnamon, source-code

In Cinnamon desktop, when I press fn + f11, I get

[image: sound adjusting]

I want to clone and modify it. How can I get its source code?

Answer (score 1):

This is the link to the Sound Applet GitHub page: [GitHub](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/tree/master/files/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/sound@cinnamon.org)